# Word for the movement of one fluid within another

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word (doesn't matter how obscure) that describes the turbulence / twisting of one substance in another.

The example I'm trying to describe is colored ink being dropped into — and flowing through — water.

I.e. "The ink [XXX] through the water."

Visually:
[image: Source: Shutterstock]
*Source: Shutterstock*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The ink **billowed** through the water.

The action is like clouds billowing in the air. The OED definition of 'billowing' does not exclude the billowing of one liquid within another.

> 2. fig. and transf. To surge, swell, undulate, roll with wavy motion.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/19033?rskey=tEEWuL&result=2#eid)

The billowing of clouds is caused by warm air currents rising upwards. The billowing of the liquid in the image is caused by gravity pulling downwards.

---

Answer (score 6):

The red ink **produced a turbulent flow** and then diffused quickly through the water.

The red ink **["diffused through"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/diffused+through)** the water.

> - diffuse something through something else - to distribute or scatter something through something else.

- The chemical process diffused the purple color through the liquid.
- Let us try to diffuse the medication through the bloodstream as rapidly as possible.
- The dye diffused through the water rapidly.

Comment: Thanks for this, however I feel as though that's more of a 'mechanical' description, when I'm after a 'visual' one — e.g. twisting / curling / flowing... Especially at the start, more like the 'convulsive propagation' that occurs in the first few seconds.

Comment: 'Diffuse' sounds more uniform. The OP is after something more random and spasmodic

Comment: @Centaurus — I wasn't looking for the phenomenon's discoverer... Have now accepted what is most helpful to what I was getting at.

Answer (score 0):

Dissipated.
The blood from the mangled head of the victim quickly dissipated in the clear waters of the millrace until it disappeared somewhere among the rushes.